# Strict Standards: Static function DAO::makeItem() should not be abstract in

Tags: abstract

I have this code, in file that have the name dao.abstract.class.php, but I am getting this error when I surf the site, and admin panel. Strict Standards: Static function DAO::makeItem() should not be abstract in dao.abstract.class.php on line 15

```
<?php

        abstract class DAO
        {
            protected $m_sql;
            protected $m_sqlId = -1;

            protected $m_orderBy;
            protected $m_orderByField;
            protected $m_orderByType;

            **abstract public function selectFromId($iditem);
            abstract public function delete($iditem);
            abstract public function save($object);
            abstract static function makeItem($resultRow);
            abstract protected function createSql();**

            protected function __construct($sql, $sortField, $sortType)
            {
                $this->m_sql = $sql;
                $this->m_orderBy = array($sortField => $sortType);
                $this->m_orderByField = $sortField;
                $this->m_orderByType = $sortType;
            }

            public function setOrderBy($order_by, $field, $type)
            {
                $this->m_orderBy = $order_by;
                $this->m_orderByField = $field;
                $this->m_orderByType = $type;
            }

            public function getOrderBy()
            {
                return $this->m_orderBy;
            }

            public function getOrderByField()
            {
                return $this->m_orderByField;
            }

            public function getOrderByType()
            {
                return $this->m_orderByType;
            }

            protected function executeQuery($objectArray = true, $renew = false)
            {
                if ($result = mysql_query($this->m_sql->getCommand($this->m_sqlId)))
                {
                    if($objectArray == true)
                    {
                        $item = array();

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            $item[] = $this->makeComplexItem($row);
                    }

                    elseif($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                        $item = $this->makeComplexItem($row);

                    else
                        $item = null;
                }

                else
                    Die(mysql_error().'<br/>'.$this->m_sql->getCommand());

                mysql_free_result($result);

                if($renew == true)
                    $this->m_sqlId = -1;

                return $item;
            }

            protected function executeOneFieldQuery($array = true)
            {
                if ($result = mysql_query($this->m_sql->getCommand()))
                {
                    if($array == true)
                    {
                        $item = array();

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                            $item[] = $row[0];
                    }

                    elseif($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                        $item = $row[0];

                    else
                        $item = null;

                    mysql_free_result($result);

                    return $item;
                }

                else
                    Die(mysql_error());
            }

            protected function executeSave($itemId)
            {
                if($itemId == -1)
                    $this->m_sql->setExecMode(Clarity::EXEC_INSERT);
                else
                    $this->m_sql->setExecMode(Clarity::EXEC_UPDATE);

                if ($itemId == -1 AND mysql_query($this->m_sql->getCommand()))
                    return mysql_insert_id();

                elseif($itemId > 0 AND mysql_query($this->m_sql->getCommand()))
                    return $itemId;

                else
                    Die(mysql_error().'<br/>'.$this->m_sql->getCommand());
            }

            protected function executeDelete()
            {
                $this->m_sql->setExecMode(Clarity::EXEC_DELETE);

                if(mysql_query($this->m_sql->getCommand()))
                    return mysql_affected_rows();

                else
                    die(mysql_error());
            }
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move this declaration to an interface.
Like this:

```
interface myInterface
{
    static function makeItem($resultRow);
}

abstract class DAO implements myInterface
{
    [...] 
}
```